# Adjust screen elements according to the screen size j2me

Tags: java-me

I have developed an app in j2me, that is supposed to run over different mobiles like Nokia, Samsung, etc. Supporting .jar files, it runs perfectly but for some of samsung devices the screen expands more than nokia's mobiles, so what I want to do is to get screens properties in a way at start so that I can adjust my texts and images according to that to make it fit for all kind of devices, any idea how can I do it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Canvas` you should get your screen properties at [`sizeChanged`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#sizeChanged%28int,%20int%29) method, but be aware that some phones do not call it properly and a simple hack will help:

```
class MainCanvas extends Canvas {

  int lastWidth, lastHeight;

  protected void sizeChanged(int w, int h) {
    lastWidth = w;
    lastHeight = h;
    // adjust your user interface to the
    // new width and height
    // ...
  }

  protected void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (super.getWidth() != lastWidth
        || super.getHeight() != lastHeight) {
      sizeChanged(super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());
    }
    // paint your user interface
    // ...
  }
}
```

I've blogged about this at http://smallandadaptive.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/sizechanged-not-called.html

Comment: well I am not using Canvas just simple form application, which changes size in different mobile sets, like Nokia and old model of samsung. I don't know how to cover it, all I had to do was to make it's display to minimum so that both could show whatever comes on the screen and I don't need to scroll down. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are worrying about drawing your own text and images, then I guess your app is canvas-based, right?  In which case, you can just call your Canvas's [`getWidth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Displayable.html#getWidth%28%29) and [`getHeight`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Displayable.html#getHeight%28%29) methods.